# Python CSV (oldschool)

Tags: python, csv

I got a problem with reading csv. I can't use panda or other libraries so I coded this piece.

```
def read_csv(path):
    
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        results = []
        newresults= []
        for line in f:
            words = line.split(',')
            print(words)
            for i in words:
                if i[-1:] == '\n':
                    i[-1:] = ""

            results.append(words)

        for lines in results:
            if lines == []:
                results.remove(lines)

        for a in results:
            newresults.append(tuple(a))
            
        return newresults
```

I can't get to remove those \n at the end of every List within the main list.

```
[('Age', 'Gender', 'Weight (kg)', 'Height (cm)\n'), ('28', 'Female', '58', '168\n'), ('33', 'Male', '', '188\n')]
```

and my code above with

```
            for i in words:
                if i[-1:] == '\n':
                    i[-1:] = ""
```

doesn't work...

Thanks in advance

Comment: `words = line.rstrip().split(',')`

Comment: Python strings are immutable. You cannot change them.

Comment: can you can use `csv` module, part of standard library?

Comment: `return [stripped.split(',') for stripped in (line.strip() for line in f) if stripped]`

Comment: @tdelaney, I would use `f.readlines()` for one-liner, cause it returns already "stripped" lines.

Comment: thank you guys!! rstrip is exactly what i was searching for

Comment: @OlvinRoght - No, it returns the same line endings as iteration. If you did `open(...).read().split("\n")` you'd get rid of the newlines, but `readlines` doesn't.